# aurora mysql - migrating large tables

Tags: mysql, migration, aws, aws-aurora, amazon-dms

We have write intensive application using aurora mysql 3.02 with 2xlarge instance size in prod. I want to migrate 10 tables (biggest one being 450GB) from 2nd aurora mysql into this prod db.

Tried using DMS, which affects the write process due to db load. On average this db have 2500-4000 iops.

Question is, if i change the instance class to bigger size, say 8xlarge. will it help, DMS & write process to get through without any issues.

If the 8xlarge helps resolve the issue, would it be recommended to run DMS with indexes on the target table OR create indexes after data is migrated?

Is there any suggestions, do's & dont's on this scenario from your experience? please advise

Answer (score 0):

There are huge speed differences depending on what technique is used for "migrate".  Please elaborate.

The 8xlarge *may* help, but not necessarily a lot.

Yes, build indexes afterward.  (But do have the `PRIMARY KEY` in place to start with.)

`mysqldump --single-transaction` should allow both writes and reads (to InnoDB tables) while the dump is running.

Comment: Thank you rick for the response. I want to copy the table (10 of them) data from server 1 to server 2 using DMS. do you think table dump and restore will be faster & efficient than using DMS? end goal is, this work should not affect the normal application writing process. please let me know if you need further clarification!!

Comment: If there are links (JOINs_) among the table, is there a chance that a copy could get inconsistencies?

Comment: I added a bit..

Comment: Thank you. provided dump command works fine!